# Vector is crashing my program

Tags: c++, oop, sfml

I've got a serious problem with my SFML game. 
I've been trying whole day to find a solution, tried diffrent things but nothing worked for me so far.
These are my .h files: 
**Bullet.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Bullet
{
    friend class Player;
    friend class Game;
    float width;
    float height;
    float x;
    float y;
    std::vector<Bullet*> projectiles;
    sf::RectangleShape bullet;
    void draw_projectiles(sf::RenderWindow &window);
    void make_projectiles();

public:
    void check();
    Bullet();
    ~Bullet();
};
```

**Game.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Bullet.h"
#include <vector>
//#include "Enemy.h"

class Game
{
    friend class Player;
    sf::RenderWindow* window;
    sf::Event* evnt;
    Player* player;
    Bullet* bullet;

public:
    void Loop();
    void game_func();
    Game();
    ~Game();
};
```

**Player.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"
#include "Bullet.h"

class Player
{
    sf::RectangleShape player;
    Bullet* bullet;
    int ammo;
    float width;
    float height;
    int x;
    int y;
    float vel;

public:
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow &window);
    void move(sf::Event &evnt, sf::RenderWindow &window);
    Player();
    ~Player();
};
```

**Here come cpp files**
**Bullet.cpp**

```
#include "Bullet.h"

void Bullet::check()
{
    x = bullet.getPosition().x;
    y = bullet.getPosition().y;
}

void Bullet::draw_projectiles(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        window.draw(projectiles[i]->bullet);
    }
}

void Bullet::make_projectiles()
{
    projectiles.push_back(new Bullet());
}

Bullet::Bullet()
{
    std::cout << "zostal utworzony nowy obiekt" << std::endl;
    width = 50;
    height = 50;
    bullet = sf::RectangleShape(sf::Vector2f(width, height));
    bullet.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
    bullet.setPosition(0, 0);
    x = bullet.getPosition().x;
    y = bullet.getPosition().y;
}

Bullet::~Bullet(){}
```

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game()
{
    window= new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "SFML Game",             
    sf::Style::Close);
    player = new Player();
}

Game::~Game(){}

void Game::Loop()
{
    while (window->isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event evnt;
        while (window->pollEvent(evnt))
        {   
            //events
            if (evnt.type==sf::Event::Closed)
                window->close();

            player->move(evnt, *window);
            window->clear();
            player->draw(*window);
            window->display();
            bullet->draw_projectiles(*window);
        }
    }
}

void Game::game_func()
{
    Game::Loop();
}
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "Player.h"

void Player::draw(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    window.draw(player);
}

void Player::move(sf::Event &evnt, sf::RenderWindow &window)
{    
    x = player.getPosition().x;
    y = player.getPosition().y;
    float width = window.getSize().x;
    float height = window.getSize().y;
    Bullet obj;

    if (evnt.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
    {
        //movement
        if (evnt.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Key::W)
        {
            if (y <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            player.move(0, -1 * vel);
        }

        if (evnt.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Key::S)
        {
            if (y >= height - Player::height)
            {
                return;
            }
            player.move(0, 1 * vel);
        }

        if (evnt.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Key::A)
        {
            if (x <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            player.move(-1 * vel, 0);
        }
        if (evnt.key.code == sf::Keyboard::D)
        {
            if(x>width-Player::width)
            {
                return;
            }
            player.move(1 * vel, 0);
        }
        if (evnt.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space)
        {
            obj.make_projectiles();
        }
    }
}

Player::Player()
{
    width = 100;
    height = 100;
    vel = 10;
    player =  sf::RectangleShape(sf::Vector2f(width, height));
    player.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    player.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(15, 20));
}

Player::~Player(){}
```

**And main.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include "Game.h"

int main()
{   
    Game gme;
    gme.game_func();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried many diffrent things and can't figure it out why it's not working. Im running in on Visual Studio 15.
So here is error that I'm getting:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.

std::_Vector_alloc<std::_Vec_base_types<Bullet *,std::allocator<Bullet *> > 
>::_Mylast(...) returned 0x18.
```

I'm aware that code is not perfect and little messy but I'm just a begginer and trying to learn new stuff.
I will appreciate any help!

Comment: You are violating the rule of 3/5/0. You are leaking memory. Use std::unique_ptr instead of raw pointers for owning pointers.

Comment: I assume you use indentation in your IDE. Select your code and use the {} option in the editor after you paste the code from your IDE. It should keep the indent.

Comment: Off topic: You have a circular dependency with player.h including qame.h and game.h including player.h. This will bite you sooner or later. More reading here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

Comment: Write something small and simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time, testing at every step, and **never add to code that doesn't work.** That way you are never more than one step away from a working version, and new bugs are very easy to isolate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered your question in my last paragraphs, you can skip to that paragraph but I sugest you take a look at all of this. First of all you should understand how should a basic game look like in code.

**The Game Logic**

You can separate the game logic in 2 main functions. The initialization and the loop.

**Initialization**

In the initialization function, you basically load everything needed for your game to run (that is only available for small games, since loading tens of gigs of sprites in memory may not be the best solution for bigger ones. With time you'll figure out the right time to load and release resources).

**The loop**

This is called the *main loop* or the *game loop*. This loop should execute 3 main functions. *Handle user input, update world, and render the world*. This loop should execute while the game is running (i.e. while the window is open)

So your main in pseudo-c++ should look something like this:

```
Init();
while (window.isOpen())
{
    HandleEvents(window);  //user input
    Update(elapsedTime);
    Render(window);
}
```

I'll explain what the functions do, what the arguments mean and how this functions are mapped to your code. Keep in mind that every function has one specific task and only that. I won't check if the user is pressing a button while I'm drawing the sprites on the screen.

**User input**

Everything from button pressing and mouse clicking to pressing the exit button and resizing the window is called *user input*. User's actions generate the so called *events*, which we handle at the beginning of each loop. Now this events are window specific(you can't control the player if the window is minimized or unfocused). That means that the window generates the events (if I'm wrong with this one technically, please correct me). This is the reason that when you are handling events you need to pass the window.

**Events**

Before handling the events, you need to understand how sf::Event is made (see more on the `sfml` page). Long story short the sf::Event is an union (only one field is valid at a time). That is, if you try to access `event.key` when the `window.pollEvent()` returned an `sf::Event::JoystickEvent` you will get an undefined behavior (I lived a long happy life without knowing what unions are, never used them and probably never will, but they are quite an interesting concept that is worth at least reading about). Ok so an event object is created by calling `window.pollEvent()` and passing to it an sf::Event instance. This function will give you events from the queue until there are no more events to be given, that's when it returns false. With that in mind, your Event handling code would look something like:

```
sf::Event ev;
while (window.pollEvent(ev))
{
    switch (ev.type)
    {
       //code for each type needed by your application
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that key events do not handle real time input (`sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed` does that). This means that if you want your character to move when you hold a button, handling it by events will result in a delay that can be the best explained by the way typing works(when you hold down 'a' for example the first character is written immediately, the rest of the input is delayed by a second before registering). This is a way of explaining it, but maybe not the most technical one(I'm asking for a little help here :) ). Anyway, this problem can be solved either by using the static methods of sf::Keyboard or by keeping a `bool` in your Player class that answers to the events `KeyPressed` and `KeyReleased`(the update will be handled based on that bool).

**World Update**

Here is your logic code(although player movement may also be handled in the events section, since it's based on them). Here you update your entities(move the enemy one more block based on his AI), move the sun around the map etc. Keep in mind that this has nothing to do with the drawing part, in this section you only change the state of your objects. In your game it means, after you launched a projective through an event triggered by the user, each frame you move the projectile. This code usually requires some sort of frame counting method.

**Frames**

A frame is an iteration of the loop, you can say that the game updates and draws itself each frame. Frames are a very important concept because they arise some issues. If the game updates itself each frame, that means that each frame the projectile is moving, so that means that his movement is dependent to the FPS your pc can run. This is a problem, because while your game may run as you want on your pc, at a stable 60 FPS rate, on mine it might run at 53, or some other random value. That means that the projectiles on my pc will move slower, and we don't want that.

**Frame independent movement**

This can be achieved by counting the frames. One way you can do that is by counting the seconds it passed since the last frame, with that in mind you can get the amount of space your entity needs to move in that specific frame. For example, you want to move your projectile with 100px/sec. If you have 2FPS that means that in 2 frames it needs to move 100px, so each frame moves `100 / 2` px. So the formula is `finalDistance / framerate`. There are more ways of doing this, but in my opinion this is the simplest to understand at the beginning. So how is this implemented in SFML? You basically keep a clock that you restart at the end of each update. `getElapsedTime` and restart does that, but restart returns the `elapsedTime` so it is better to call it once, since calling them one by one may result in different times and desyncs.

```
sf::Clock clock;
while (window.isOpen())
{
    HandleEvents(window);
    Update(clock.restart());
    Render(window);
}
```

And you simply move your entities with `move(vector * clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds())` since `sf::Vector` has `operator*` overloaded for floats(the return type of `asSeconds()`).

**Rendering**

The rendering part may be very complicated, but `sfml` makes it "simple and fast". Basically it works like that: You clear the screen, you draw your entities, you display the screen. The more technical answer is the following: the window consists of 2 buffers, one visible and one hidden. The visible one is the one you see on the screen. When you call `clear()` you basically clear the hidden one, `draw()` draws also on the hidden window, and finally `display()` swaps the buffers. 
That means that you won't see any results unless you call `window.display()`, and you'll get a window xp experience if you don't call `clear()` before drawing. So the Render function might look like this:

```
 window.clear();
 window.draw(player); //or player.draw(window) based on your implementation
 //other draws
 window.display();
```

**Your question**

What happens in your code is that you try to access things that don't exist. You add one projectile at a time, but each frame you draw 10 of them.

**The solution**

Keep a counter of your objects. Since you are using a vector that is already provided, you have `std::vector::size` that returns exactly what you expect, so your code will turn into something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < yourProjectiles.size(); i++)
{
    window.draw(yourProjectiles[i]->bullet);
}
```

Alternatively you can use iterators(look them up):

```
for (auto it = yourProjectiles.begin(); it != yourProjectiles.end(); ++it)
{
    window.draw(it->bullet);
}
```

**Memory management**

You don't deallocate memory. You have to look into dynamic memory allocation. The base principle is that for every new there should be a delete. The deallocation part should be handled most of the time in the destructor of the class. I think someone may suggested to use smart pointers(`std::shared_ptr`) so manage your memory, but I can't recommend you that since you are at the beginning. Smart pointers are a concept you should keep in mind, but as you started out it is better to face the struggles of manual memory management(until you get used to it).

**Code organizing**

A class should be made for only one purpose. When you create a class called Bullet, it is expected that this Bullet will represent one projectile in your game, but when your Bullet makes "projectiles" and stores projectiles, it becomes a paranormal entity. Your bullet atm holds pointers to instances of other bullets that hold pointers to instances of other bullets. This is a total mess. Unless you want to create a graph or a tree of some sort you don't have any reason to store pointers of instances of the same class.

**Too many friends**

If every class is friend with every class, what is your reason of creating private fields? Friend is a very powerful concept and should be used with care, only in cases you DON'T have other options. The only reason I would avoid this keyword is the messiness it creates. It creates the same effect as public attributes. When everything is accessible from everywhere, everything can be destroyed from everywhere. When you create a small set of methods that manipulate your attributes, you know where the problem is.

**Conclusion**

I might suggest looking a little more into c++ and after that debug your game, or recreate it from scratch. While I know how it feels to try something new, you should always be careful to not shoot yourself in the leg, and don't be afraid to go back to the basics when you stumble into such errors. You have problems managing memory? Read more about dynamic memory allocation, do some example apps using it. Besides that I noticed you are still at the beginning with using classes. I'd say practice makes perfect. Look at other people code, even these 3rd party libraries like sfml may give you some hints on good class practices. The good thing is that it is not needed to look at the source code of those libraries, you just use their interface. If you like it, it means it is good written and you may borrow a part of that style and implement in your classes. I'll conclude this by saying that I am very happy and eager to help you via email if you have any other question regarding anything.

Comment: Curious false positive. Are there many links in your full-length answer?

Comment: Hmm there was one to the sfml page but I removed it(with no success). The answer however was quite long(maybe around 50 lines)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rW8PMu8m hope I did it right. Thank you very much.

Comment: There you go :)

Comment: Wow! Thank  you so much for your valuable message! That's a lot of new informations and I will try to follow them. I would love more help from you especially via email or by anything else. Is there any way on Stack to send private message?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but I added my email address in the "about me" field. Feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are attempting to access ten projectiles:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    window.draw(projectiles[i]->bullet);
}
```

But you only add one at a time:

```
projectiles.push_back(new Bullet());
```

Comment: Actually this 10 thing is left from one of my experiments, because I kept on getting error with vector.size() I want to make a new object of bullet everytime I press space. Add it to vector and draw on every frame.

Comment: Well, it will definitely cause a crash because it's attempting to access elements which don't exist.

Comment: So what do you suggest me to do? What should I read about to understand more of it?

Comment: @Sniadek: `for (auto& projectile : projectiles)` iterates over all the projectiles in the vector. No more, no less.